# JSF Converters - Error de validación: el valor no es válido

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en JSF en la que utilizo un control `<h:selectOneListbox .../>`. para el que tengo definido un `Converter`.

A continuación muestro un bloque simplificado de dicho control, que contiene un `panelGrid` con un botón de `Guardar` y un selector de lista:

```
<h:panelGrid cellpadding = "5" columns = "4" >
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar"
        update=":dmContadoresConsumoForm:edicionContadorConsumoPnl"
        disabled="#{!contadoresConsumoBean.contadorCentroEditable}"
        actionListener="#{contadoresConsumoBean.guardarContador}"/>
    <h:outputText value = "Producto" />
    <h:selectOneListbox
        id = "productoSel"
        size = "1"
        value = "#{contadoresConsumoBean.productoSeleccionado}"
        disabled = "#{!contadoresConsumoBean.contadorCentroEditable}"
        style = "width:100%" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue = "0"
            itemLabel = "" / >
        <f:selectItems
            value = "#{contadoresConsumoBean.productos}" 
            var = "producto"
            itemValue = "#{producto.id}"
            itemLabel = "#{producto.nombre}" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>

<!-- ... -->

</h:panelGrid>
```

Tengo definido un `Converter` para los objetos de tipo `Producto`, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productoConverter")
@SessionScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = Producto.class)
public class ProductoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        long id = -1;
        try{
            id = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        Transaction t = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        try{
            Producto e = new ProductoServiceImpl().find(id);
            t.commit();
            return e;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            t.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Producto){
            return ((Producto)value).getId().toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando presiono el botón para Guardar cambios, salta el error:

```
dmContadoresConsumoForm:productoSel: Error de validación: el valor no es válido
```

He probado a depurar el `Converter` y parece que funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿puedes añadir la traza de error o el log de cuando haces la acción?

Comment: El problema es que no veo que lance ninguna traza por Tomcat, estoy intentando averiguar de donde sale el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, el error se da debido a que hay que sobreescribir los métodos `equals(Object object)` y `hashCode()` en el bean sobre el que se aplica el Converter.

Por otra parte, en el fichero xhtml, he modificado el valor del atributo `itemValue="#{producto}"`, de modo que la solución queda del siguiente modo:

### xhtml:

```
<h:panelGrid cellpadding = "5" columns = "4" >
    <p:commandButton value="Guardar"
        update=":dmContadoresConsumoForm:edicionContadorConsumoPnl"
        disabled="#{!contadoresConsumoBean.contadorCentroEditable}"
        actionListener="#{contadoresConsumoBean.guardarContador}"/>
    <h:outputText value = "Producto" />
    <h:selectOneListbox
        id = "productoSel"
        size = "1"
        value = "#{contadoresConsumoBean.productoSeleccionado}"
        disabled = "#{!contadoresConsumoBean.contadorCentroEditable}"
        style = "width:100%" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue = "0"
            itemLabel = "" / >

        <!-- Cambio. Antiguo: itemValue = "#{producto.id}"-->
        <f:selectItems
            value = "#{contadoresConsumoBean.productos}" 
            var = "producto"
            itemValue = "#{producto}"
            itemLabel = "#{producto.nombre}" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>

<!-- ... -->

</h:panelGrid>
```

### ProductoConverter.java

El converter no tenía ningún error, por lo que sigue igual:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productoConverter")
@SessionScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = Producto.class)
public class ProductoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        long id = -1;
        try{
            id = Long.parseLong(value);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
        Transaction t = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();
        try{
            Producto e = new ProductoServiceImpl().find(id);
            t.commit();
            return e;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            t.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof Producto){
            return ((Producto)value).getId().toString();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Producto.java

En esta clase sobreescribo los métodos `equals(Object object)` y `hashCode()`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "producto")
public class Producto implements Serializable {

    // Propiedades

    // Getters y Setters

    // Constructores

    // Métodos

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Producto)) {
            return false;
        }
        Producto other = (Producto) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: JSF hace uso intensivo de las buenas prácticas de Java y de estándares como Java Bean and Java Naming. Quizás por ello es que no encontrabas como resolverlo. Pero como veo que usas JSF 2.x en lugar de colocar el `id` del elemento como valor podías usar el objeto directamente y así te ahorrabas crear el converter. Para el caso donde el usuario no ha seleccionado nada, puedes usar `itemValue="#{null}"` y el objeto que se enviara al servidor será `null`.

Comment: Tomo nota. Gracias!